# Tensorflow-gpu runs out of host memory after exactly one epoch

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to run the cyclegan-1 model (https://github.com/leehomyc/cyclegan-1) on the provided horse2zebra dataset in order to test my tensorflow-gpu install.

Everything seems to work fine at first, until the end of the first batch, when my system freezes up for a minute and I get this error:

```
2017-10-26 15:23:10.103303: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-10-26 15:23:10.103321: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592
2017-10-26 15:23:10.103592: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-10-26 15:23:10.103599: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 7730940928
./run_cyclegan_oct_26_2017: line 1: 15025 Killed                  python3 -m CycleGAN_TensorFlow.main --to_train=2 --log_dir=CycleGAN_TensorFlow/output/cyclegan/exp_01 --config_filename=CycleGAN_TensorFlow/configs/exp_01.json --checkpoint_dir=CycleGAN_TensorFlow/output/cyclegan/exp_01/20171026-005834
```

I searched similar problems and thought that this was caused by tensorflow trying to allocate RAM used for system processes.

However, after killing the x server and running from a tty, I got the same error at exactly the same place: right after it finishes processing the first batch.

It seems like tensorflow is trying to allocate around 8GB, though this is less than my system memory.

Is the problem that I need to limit Tensorflow's memory usage? I've read a lot about limiting its GPU memory usage but not RAM.

My setup:

- Memory 15.6 GiB
- Processor Intel core i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10Ghz x 4
- Graphics GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
- OS type 64-bit
- Plenty of disk space
- Using python3

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: I'm new to Tensorflow but I'm fairly sure `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` signals that your GPU is out of memory, not a reference to your RAM. Your graphics card has 6GB of memory and you're trying to allocate 8.5GB and 7.7.GB.

Comment: A couple of other posts said that 'host' memory meant RAM, but I could be wrong. Not sure what I'd do in either case, though.

Comment: After your first epoch are you trying to check a validation dataset that's much larger than your mini batches?

Comment: I don't think so; I'm just trying to run the model without any changes.

Comment: In my case I DID have a larger batch size on the validation dataset than training, obvious in retrospect but I needed the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when searching for the cause of my similar problem: program can run during training but got `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` when trying to save the model with `tf.train.saver.save`. I post my solution here for others reference.

For my problem, the cause is the upper limit of the files allowed to open in a thread. Because I opened too many files in data generator without closing them, I hit the upper limit (default 1024). This causes the failure of opening model file for write.  The problem is solved by [increase the upper limit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18022) or close all the files before saving. It took me a long while to figure this out because the error message is not relevant to file I/O :(

Not sure if `tf.train_and_evaluate` will save file before evaluation. But one thing you can check is to make sure if the output file (e.g. model) can be opened properly.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have a similar problem with `model.save_weights`.  But have you an explanation about the host OOM when saving the model ?